# React native not encoding images correctly in web

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native, base64, react-native-web

Hi I want to show a local image in my react native web app. But it does not work correctly.

src of img tag: `data:image/png;base64,bW9kdWxlLmV4cG9ydHMgPSBfX3dlYnBhY2tfcHVibGljX3BhdGhfXyArICI0NzFhMWFkMzQyNjU5Mjg5NDMzZTA1YTYxMWQyMDZmOC5wbmciOw==`

code:

````
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.menuButton}>
    <Image
    source={require('./user.png')}
    style={styles.imageIconStyle}/>
</TouchableOpacity>```
````

Comment: image src is ok in browser preview but seems to be corrupted when you save it, have you tried it with other image not under base64 encryption ?

Comment: I think React automatically encode images. Because I didn't do it manually